# DeLeaker in remote mode?

Tags: c#, c++, gdi

I have to find GDI leaks in my source for an application that is running remotely.
I am using DELeaker for this purpose but somehow i am not able to find any use.Can DeLeaker be used for remote applications?If not is there any other application for detecting GDI Leaks for applications running remotely?

Comment: Can you describe the environment in more detail? GDI does not support remote display, so it's not clear how the application could be running remotely. Or what is preventing you from running it locally for testing.

Comment: The Application is running on a specialized dedicated system and cannot be run locally.At the same time i do not have visual studio installed on the remote system so that i can copy my source there.So i have to do remote debugging only

Answer (score 3):

Deleaker supports the local debugging only.

*I am author of Deleaker. I hope to add remote debugging.*

Comment: You are wrong - deleaker supports remote debugging as the local debugging. This opportunity was added in the last release.

Comment: According to deleaker developer Artem Razin, despite the Deleaker does not support remote debuging it can be run as standalone on remote machime.

Comment: ... "it seems" ... were you unsure, despite _being_ the author of said product? It's customary to disclose ones affiliation with a product, if one exists.